# Enviar Post com dados formulário através de Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Quero criar uma função que move todos os registros selecionados de uma tabela para outra. O usuário seleciona múltiplos registros em uma lista, clica no botão mover, nesse momento o sistema abre o formulário para o usuário escolher a tabela para qual o registro será movido e clica em salvar.

Tenho o código JQuery que envia um post com o ID de todos os registros selecionados. Mas preciso que além do ID, esse código envie também a informação das opções escolhida no formulário.

Código do formulário

```
<form method="post">        
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="divAction" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label">Escolha a tabela</label>
            <select name="id_tabela" id="id_tabela" required="" >
                <option value="1">– Tabela 1 –</option>
                <option value="2">– Tabela 2 –</option>                 
            </select>           
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-success transfer">Salvar alterações</button>                                   
    </div>  
</div>
```

Código JQuery

```
jQuery('.transfer').on('click', function(e) { 
            var allVals = [];  
            $(".sub_chk:checked").each(function() {  
                allVals.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
            });  
            //alert(allVals.length); return false;  
            if(allVals.length <=0)  {  

                jQuery(function(){swal({
                  title: 'ATENÇÃO',
                  text: 'Nenhum registro selecionado',
                  confirmButtonColor: "#46be8a",
                  timer: 5000
                }).then(
                  function () {},
                  // handling the promise rejection
                  function (dismiss) {
                    if (dismiss === 'timer') {
                      console.log('I was closed by the timer')
                    }
                  }
                );
            });     

            }else {  

             swal({
                      title: "Deseja Mover?",
                      text: "Todos os registros selecionados serão movidos para a lista escolhida",
                      type: "warning",
                      showCancelButton: true,
                      confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                      confirmButtonText: 'Sim, Mover',
                      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                      closeOnConfirm: false,
                      //closeOnCancel: false
                    },
                    function() {
                        var ids = []; // cria o array                           
                        $.each(allVals, function( index, value ) {
                            //$('table tr').filter("[data-row-id='" + value + "']").remove();
                            id = value;  
                            ids.push(id); // armazena no array
                        });

                        var formTest = document.createElement('form');
                        formTest.setAttribute("method", "post");
                        formTest.setAttribute("action", "");
                        var post = document.createElement("input");
                        post.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                        post.setAttribute("name", "idsTransf");
                        post.setAttribute("value", ids);
                        formTest.appendChild(post); 
                        document.body.appendChild(formTest);
                        formTest.submit();

                    }); 



            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não sei os dados que tem a tabela eu vou te dar uma solução genérica pra você aplicar.

Vamos supor que a tabela tenha a coluna Id e outra conteudo. Então do mesmo jeito que você pegou a Id você pega o conteúdo, só que na hora de salvar, você salva em uma array de objetos. Vou te dar um exemplo de como criar pra você ver no console como ela fica:

```js
var obj = {
    'registro1' : {
        'id' : '',
        'conteudo' : ''
    },
    'registro2' : {
        'id' : '',
        'conteudo' : ''
    }
};
obj.registro1.id = 'input1';
obj.registro1.conteudo = 'input2';
obj.registro2.id = 'input3';
obj.registro2.conteudo = 'input4';

console.log(obj);
```